# Phone book with hashmap implementation in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have to make an app that would simulate a phone book in java, using hash map(s). I want to implement 2 methods for search(enter a name to get a number and enter a number to get a name).

Is there any way to make both methods work with only 1 hash map defined like this `HashMap<Person, Number> pb = new HashMap<>();`(where Person and Number are classes)?

Comment: This should be fairly possible.

Comment: You could, but you would need to iterate through every value to find a number. Just an observation: Numbers are guaranteed to be unique. Names are not. It makes more sense for the number to be the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you need 2 `Maps` in this case `Map<Person, Number>` and `Map<Number, Person>` if you want to have a fast access to your data with only one map you would need to iterate over the values which is of course much slower.

You can also use a [BiMap](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/65e6bd2efb54b9f6a94de0771db698cea8d2a1ca/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.java) from Google guava to do both with one map

> A bimap (or "bidirectional map") is a map that preserves the
>   uniqueness of  its values as well as that of its keys. This constraint
>   enables bimaps to  support an "inverse view", which is another bimap
>   containing the same entries  as this bimap but with reversed keys and
>   values

Answer (score 0):

This can be done via a BidiMap (Bidirectional map) available with apache commons collection. See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/BidiMap.html for more details. But, in this case, names and numbers has to be unique. If it is not possible, then you will either have to maintain two maps or use one map and iterate the values.